# OSX how can I debug malloc errors when extending python with C++?

Tags: python, c++, macos, memory-leaks, malloc

I extended python by creating a C++ wrapper to established libraries coded in C++11. When I test my code, I receive the following error:

```
python(46809,0x7fff728e7300) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=140735135109120) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
python(46809,0x7fff728e7300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff73bc4c70: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I have probed this code and confirmed that this is happening inside the external libraries, which are pre-compiled. `valgrind`'s output was not useful, and the `-fsanitize=address` flag leads to this error: `Symbol not found: ___asan_option_detect_stack_use_after_return`. Can anyone reccomend new approaches I can take in debugging this memory leak?

Comment: I have updated my comment to reflect that my wrapper is C++ and the compiled libraries are C++11. Thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Mavericks solved this problem. APperently the upgrade re-wrote some crucial `/System` files.